# GCloud adding users to VM based on local username

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

My company uses Google Cloud Computing to manage several VMs.

For connecting to said VMs, I have a username that is slightly different than my username on my local machine. For instance, my local user is `firstnamelastname` where my username on the VMs is `firstname`. However, I'm noticing that in the `/home/` directory of the VMs a second user is getting created as `firstnamelastname` alongside `firstname`.

I've checked the metadata of the project, there are SSH keys present for both usernames, though it is the same key for both. I've manually deleted thet key for the incorrect username from the metadata, and on the VM I've run `sudo userdel -r firstnamelastname`. However, after I exit and the run the gcloud command to reconnect, `gcloud ssh firstname@address`, it seems that somehow gcloud is picking up the ssh key as if it belonged to `firstnamelastname` still. So I get connected as `firstname`, but then looking in `/home/` again I see that `firstnamelastname` is back. Then I go refresh the metadata in the cloud console and see that the SSH key is back and associated with `firstnamelastname`

I'm sure there's some metadata somewhere that needs to be adjusted to prevent this, but I have no idea where to look for it and have come up empty in my attempts to search for this particular issue on my own. Does anyone have any guidance on how I can identify what is causing the incorrect user to be recreated every time I connect to the VM?